# How do I change the visibility of a Button in one activity based on the visibility of an ImageView in a different activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

My app lets a user design a camper van interior by placing items on a floor plan, I then want a different activity to show hyperlinks to websites selling the items selected.

I am trying to use Intents to pass the visibility of an image to the t4shop activity, then make the relevant button visible based on this information.

The activity with the floor plan is t4.java and the activity with the links is t4shop.java.

To send the visibility state, in the t4.java activity i put

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_t4);

    ImageView Evomotion = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.evomotion);

    if (Evomotion.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, t4shop.class);
        intent.putExtra("makebuttonvisible", true);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

To receive the visibility state and change the visibility of the button in t4shop.java I put

```
    public Button evobutton;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_t4shop);
    evobutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.evobutton);
    evobutton.setOnClickListener(this);

    if(getIntent().getBooleanExtra("makebuttonvisible", true)){
        evobutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        evobutton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

At present this code is just displaying the button regardless, I have tried a couple of other methods but I am very new to this and keep going round in circles of failure.

Do i need to define anything else in the manifest or somewhere else in the activities?

Thanks in advance,

Steve

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of t4.java.  It looks like it's always going to do the same thing based on the way you defined the visibility of the ImageView in the layout.  Either it immediately starts t4shop, or doesn't.  That seems weird to me.

Comment: Are you setting "intent.putExtra("makebuttonvisible", false);" at any point in your code?

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of `getBooleanExtra()` is the default value, which will be returned if the key for the extra isn't present. You only pass the extra if the `ImageView` inside the first `Activity` is visible, meaning that if it's not visible - there will be no value passed. In first scenario `getBooleanExtra()` will return `true` - this is what you passed via the `Intent`. In the second scenario it will still be `true`, since you didn't pass any value at all. The solution would be to either pass the value explicitly every time, even if `ImageView` is not visible, or have the default value be `false`.

Comment: Hi Egor,  I have tried it with the value as false but I still have no success.  I want the Intent to be sent to the other activity but I don't want to start the other activity until a later stage.  How can I see if the intent is being transmitted or received?  Thanks, Steve.

Answer (score 0):

The 
`if(getIntent().getBooleanExtra("makebuttonvisible", true))` is always true.
The second parameter "true" is the default value if it cannot find the BooleanExtra. So set it to false instead of true.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this to get the value of visibility

```
 if(getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("makebuttonvisible")){
        evobutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        evobutton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if(getIntent().getBooleanExtra("makebuttonvisible", true)){
        evobutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        evobutton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
```

to

```
 if(getIntent().getBooleanExtra("makebuttonvisible", false)){
        evobutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        evobutton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
```